# Programm running from USB with certain Device ID or not

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to combine this code:
If the USB present or not with certain number, and is the programm running from that USB drive.

With this I get the USB numbers, and check if it is present:

```
 Dim USBClass As New System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_USBHub")
 Dim USBCollection As System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection = USBClass.GetInstances()
 Dim USB As System.Management.ManagementObject
 Dim allDrives() As IO.DriveInfo = IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()
 Dim d As IO.DriveInfo

 Dim MyDrive As String = Path.GetPathRoot(Application.StartupPath)

 If GetDriveType(MyDrive) = DriveType.Removable Then
     'Program running from USB
 Else
     MessageBox.Show("Sorry.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
 End If

 For Each USB In USBCollection

     Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("Device ID = " & USB("deviceid").ToString())
 Next USB
 Dim d As IO.DriveInfo

 For Each d In allDrives
     If d.IsReady = True AndAlso d.DriveType = IO.DriveType.Removable Then
         ListBox1.Items.Add(d.VolumeLabel).ToString()
         If IO.DriveType.Removable Then
         End If
     Else
         If d.IsReady = True And Not d.DriveType = DriveType.Removable Then
             ListBox1.Items.Add(d.RootDirectory).ToString()
         End If
     End If
 Next
```

Check if it is there:

```
  Dim found As String = ""
  Dim foo As String
  foo = "Device ID = USB\VID_0951&PID_1666\4CEDFB74A3A4F791091722"

  For i As Integer = 0 To Keuze.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
      If Keuze.ListBox1.Items(i).ToString = foo Then
          found = (i)
      End If
  Next

  If found = "" Then
      MessageBox.Show("Sorry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
  Else
        MessageBox.Show("Jep!")
  End If
```

That works.
And this for running on USB or not:

```
Public Function GetDriveType(ByVal Drive As String) As DriveType
    Dim MyDrive As New DriveInfo(Drive)
    Return MyDrive.DriveType
End Function

im MyDrive As String = Path.GetPathRoot(Application.StartupPath)

If GetDriveType(MyDrive) = DriveType.Removable Then
    'Program running from USB
Else
    'Program running from PC
End If
```

The above code is for:

- is the USB present with the right number.
- and is it running from USB.

But if I put the programm on a second USB and leave the first USB with the rigt number it works also. Because it is running from the second USB and the right number is also there on a other USB port.

**The Question**

How do I check if programm is running on this USB?

`foo = "Device ID = USB\VID_0951&PID_1666\4CEDFB74A3A4F791091722"`